# How can't I get an uninterrupted counter across nested enumerations?

Tags: enumitem

I have an outer enumeration `foopart`, and a nested one `foochap`. I'd like the counter for `foochap` to *not* reset each time a new `foochap` environment is created inside `foopart`. Subsidiary question: how to manually set the counter for lists created with `\newlist` say ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlist{foopart}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist[foopart,1]{label=\Roman*}
\newlist{foochap}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist[foochap,1]{resume, label=\textbf{\arabic*)}}

\newlist{qux}{enumerate*}{2}
\setlist[qux,1]{label=\Roman*}
\setlist[qux,2]{resume,label=\textbf{\arabic*)}}

\begin{document}

\begin{foochap}
\item W
\end{foochap}
\begin{foochap}
\item X
\end{foochap}\par

\begin{foopart}
\item 
  \begin{foochap}
  \item Y 
  \end{foochap}
\item 
  \begin{foochap}
  \item Z % expect 4)
  \end{foochap}
\end{foopart}\par

\begin{qux}
\item 
  \begin{qux}
  \item W
  \end{qux}
\item 
  \begin{qux}
  \item X % expect 2)
  \end{qux}
\item 
  \begin{qux}
  \item Y % expect 3)
  \end{qux}
\item 
  \begin{qux}
  \item Z % expect 4)
  \end{qux}
\end{qux}\par

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly does "manually set the counter" mean here? Do you want your counter to start from something different than 1? If so, you could use the `start=x` option with x=number you want your counter to start from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess, the following is the output you would expect:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlist{foopart}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist[foopart,1]{label=\Roman*}
\newlist{foochap}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist[foochap,1]{resume=chap, label=\textbf{\arabic*)}}

\newlist{qux}{enumerate*}{2}
\setlist[qux,1]{label=\Roman*}
\setlist[qux,2]{resume=qux,label=\textbf{\arabic*)}}

\begin{document}

\begin{foochap}[series=chap]
\item W
\end{foochap}
\begin{foochap}
\item X
\end{foochap}\par

\begin{foopart}
\item 
  \begin{foochap}
  \item Y 
  \end{foochap}
\item 
  \begin{foochap}
  \item Z % expect 4)
  \end{foochap}
\end{foopart}\par

\begin{qux}[series=qux]
\item 
  \begin{qux}
  \item W
  \end{qux}
\item 
  \begin{qux}
  \item X % expect 2)
  \end{qux}
\item 
  \begin{qux}
  \item Y % expect 3)
  \end{qux}
\item 
  \begin{qux}
  \item Z % expect 4)
  \end{qux}
\end{qux}\par

\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting how `foochap` doesn't have its own (say) `series=foochap` by default, if nothing else is specified.